# Odd encoding requires two decodes to get right

Tags: ruby, url-encoding, urldecode

I have a string

```
"R&amp;B%2FSoul"
```

It appears to be URL encoded.  But decoding it produces odd results:

```
URI.unescape("R&amp;B%2FSoul") => "R&amp;B/Soul"
```

It seems to take care of part of it, but not all of it.  If I do

```
CGI::unescapeHTML("R&amp;B%2FSoul") => "R&B%2FSoul"
```

So inorder to get the right value out I need to decode it twice

```
CGI.unescape(CGI::unescapeHTML("R&amp;B%2FSoul")) => "R&B/Soul"
```

Anyone understand what's going on here?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert, but it looks like you've got a mix of encodings in that string, hence the need to decode using two different techniques. Where did you get it?  If it were URL (Percent) encoded, it would look like this probably:

```
R%26B%2FSoul
```

Since `&` is `%26`.

Comment: Out on the wilds of the internet there are all sorts of weird double/triple/n encoded strings. I used to write spiders and ran into that stuff all the time when people didn't pay attention.

Answer (score 0):

The `%nn` is a URI encoded value and the `&...;` is an HTML encoded value.  I would expect to see the `&` as `%26` since that's a variable separator.